# What's the correct data structure for given C# code

Tags: c#, c++

Following is the Equal subset [Number Partitioning](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/dynamic-programming-set-18-partition-problem/) problem.

My aim is to not just get the boolean result suggesting whether a solution is feasible (as ahown on the link above), but also to find the relevant subset.

Following is the [C++ solution](http://ideone.com/wlL49q) (using Ideone), which use an array, which is dynamic in its size for C++, but when I convert it into the [C# solution](http://ideone.com/Ioswlr), my challenge is using the correct data structure, since neither a `int[]`, nor a `List<int>` can serve the same purpose, as it can be seen in the `C# solution Main`, I take a value for array size and fill only n-2 th index, but leave the n-1 th index as default 0, else it leads to `index out of range exception`.

Can anyone suggest a better data structure, to make it similar and flexible to C++ program

Comment: `int solution[n];` that's not valid C++ and can be done way better with `std::vector<int>`. Anyway, just resize your `List<int>` in C#.

Comment: It is C++, working code

Comment: No, it makes use of a GCC extension called variable-length arrays.

Comment: It's a gcc extension, named "variable length array"

Comment: Yes and how to achieve the same in C#, `List<int>` being an array internally is not helping, once allocated. I mean I cannot access the index beyond the valid value, which is not the case for C++ variable length arrays

Comment: If your C# solution with arrays is throwing on what you think to be the n-1 th index, then you are accessing a different index than what you think. Meaning: if you ported the code correctly, then your C++ solution is probably already violating array bounds and you are just unlucky enough that C++ is allowing you to shoot yourself instead of throwing errors beforehand.

Comment: @grek40 Did you get a chance to review the code, these are simple snippets, with both providing correct result for multiple inputs, there's no point guessing without an evaluation. Some where as it seems C++ dynamic arrays doesn't have a replacement in C#

Comment: @MrinalKamboj in your C++ solution, put the following code before line 40: `if (i < 0 || i >= n) cout << "ERROR!" << endl`. Or in other words: `if(sum<0 || i>n)` is not a sufficient bounds check, since an array of length `n` doesn't allow access to index `n`.

Comment: @grek40 Thanks for the review

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As discussed in the comments, the source of your confusion is the fact, that your C++ solution is accessing index `n` in an array of size `n`, which results in undefined behavior (this time, it is running without reporting any error).

Also, the way you create your C++ array is a GCC specific language extension.

The mostly 1:1 port of your C++ array to C# would be (as you already discovered)

```
int solution[n]; // C++ language extension
int[] solution = new int[n]; // C#, cleanup is handled by GC
```

This will work as soon as you corrected your indexing problems in the original solution.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, I am able to get it working with `List<int>` post using condition `i > n-1`, which means never out of range index behaviour